# Strange problem MFC c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I am making an simple application in MFC /c++.This code is to ceate a dialog in CWinApp class.It compile fine and also run fine but only if i run it from VStudio.But if i run it directly,runtime error occured and program crashed.

```
CMyDialog dlg;
m_pMainWnd = (CWnd*)&dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
```

but if i used the code just below,then everything is fine.I could't understand this behaviour.

```
CMyDialog *dlg=new CMyDialog();
m_pMainWnd = (CWnd*)dlg;
dlg->DoModal();
```

This type of thing were happened many times before also for me in some other past  C++(non MFC) projects. 
please specify this to me.

Comment: Could you post the call stack from the first case when the problem occurs?

Comment: I actually have understood the problem.but here the call stack.(error in release mode only).
> ntdll.dll!7c911e58()  
  [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
  ntdll.dll!7c918251()  
  ntdll.dll!7c911c76()  
  ntdll.dll!7c911538()  
  ntdll.dll!7c9106eb()  
  ntdll.dll!7c9140bb()  
  kernel32.dll!7c801a4f()  
  ntdll.dll!7c90e234()  
  kernel32.dll!7c8110db()  
  kernel32.dll!7c801a24()  
  ...others also but comment size Overflow of StackOverflow
  ...

Comment: In such cases I usually select "debug" right after the crash. Assuming Visual Studio is opened with the DEBUG version, even if you double click the executable you can still debug the program after the crash and get to the bottom of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case the object is being destroyed (when dlg goes out of scope) but is still pointed to by m_pMainWnd. It's possible/likely that something is causing m_pMainWnd to be used and accessing an object which no longer exists.

Change the first example to:

```
CMyDialog dlg;
m_pMainWnd = (CWnd*)&dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
m_pMainWnd = NULL;
```

If that solves the problem, the reason you got away with it in the second case is that the object was not destroyed (although since m_pMainWnd points to it, MFC may be destroying it for you when the program shuts down; indeed, that may be the source of the crash in the other case).

Comment: thanks Leo,but please tell me that why during compiling in VS2008 the first case runs fine.

Comment: one more thing i want to tell that the 1st case was working all good before 2 days ago.the problem started when i compile it again.and also when i puts the exe file in c:\ drive it runs fine but in other folders it strangly crashes (if 1st case).

Comment: If the problem is caused by accessing a freed object then it's entirely possible that you just got away with it before (because the pointer happened to point to readable memory which didn't contain data that caused a crash; maybe the data even still held the old object's state from before it was deleted) but now some change in the program happens to have moved things around a bit and is causing things to crash. Just a guess, though. Does setting the pointer to NULL fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between these two code blocks is that in the first, `dlg` is going to be destroyed at the end of the block, and in the second, it's not destroyed in any code here.

Given the rest of your program, is dlg still needed at the end of the block it's declared in?  If so, you need to use something like the second block.

Alternatively, it's possible that `DoModal` calls `delete(this)` (directly or indirectly) -- in that case, `dlg` must be made with `new`.

Comment: AFAIK `DoModal` does not do that.  I have created dialogs on the stack and called `DoModal` in MFC for as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set `m_pMainWnd` to a window which will not exist anymore when the dialog is closed, and this typically happens *before* the dialog destruction, just when you close the dialog (when the `DoModal` returns).

I resolved this problem by creating a dummy window and using it as the main window:

```
class CDummyWindow : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CDummyWindow()
    {
        Create(NULL, NULL);
    }
};

Class::InitInstance()
{
  ...
  CDummyWindow win;
  m_pMainWnd = &win;
  ...
  return FALSE;
}
```

Be sure that you `return FALSE` indicating that the app should stop.